# What is the difference between "export MY_VAR=123 && npx package …" and "MY_VAR=123 npx package …"

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables

The use case is to export an environment variable just for using it in the following `npx package …` command.

What is the difference between `export MY_VAR=123 && npx package…` and `MY_VAR=123 npx package…`?

Does it matter which option I use?
If there is no difference, I would tend to use the second option as it is shorter.

Comment: the first one, MY_VAR will be set after the command and persist in the session. the second 1, it's available in the command only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both commands will run npx with the environment variables MY_VAR=123

The difference is that with 'export MY_VAR=123' the variable will stay in the shell environment variable, and will apply to all future programs (until reset, or changes).

When you use `MY_VAR=123 npx package…` the variable is set for the environment of the `npx` command, but will not apply to future programs.

```
var=FOO echo "$var"
Output: "FOO"

(echo "X $var")
Output: "X " since var not set.

export var=BAR
echo "X $var"
Output: "X BAR"

(echo "X $var")
Output: "X BAR"
```

In general, if you need environment variable for single program, use the VAR=value VAR2=value2 ... command argument, as it eliminate the need to 'clean' the environment from program specific settings, and reduces the risk of unintended environment variables will be passed around.